# Can't reference a permission helper class

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-7

Asked in **[Liferay Forums](https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/development/re-re-can-t-reference-a-permission-helper-class)**

I've created a permission helper class for my Question entity following the steps explained [here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360034568171-Assigning-Permissions-to-Resources):

```
package net.carlosduran.nomedes.web.internal.security.permission.resource;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.permission.PermissionChecker;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.permission.resource.ModelResourcePermission;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

import net.carlosduran.nomedes.db.model.Question;

@Component(immediate = true)
public class QuestionPermission {

    public static boolean contains(
            PermissionChecker permissionChecker, Question question, String actionId) throws PortalException {

        return _questionModelResourcePermission.contains(permissionChecker, question, actionId);
    }

    public static boolean contains(
            PermissionChecker permissionChecker, long entryId, String actionId) throws PortalException {

        return _questionModelResourcePermission.contains(permissionChecker, entryId, actionId);
    }

    @Reference(
            target = "(model.class.name=net.carlosduran.nomedes.db.model.Question)", 
            unbind = "-")
    protected void setEntryModelPermission(ModelResourcePermission<Question> modelResourcePermission) {

        _questionModelResourcePermission = modelResourcePermission;
    }

    private static ModelResourcePermission<Question> _questionModelResourcePermission;

}
```

In a MVCRenderCommand class I reference it this way:

```
@Reference
protected QuestionPermission _questionPermission;
```

If I include this reference, the render class doesn't work (I've tried it with different render classes).

In the moment I delete it, the render class works without a problem.

The code for the **service.xml** file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.4.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_4_0.dtd">

<service-builder dependency-injector="ds" package-path="net.carlosduran.nomedes.db">
    <namespace>Nomedes</namespace>
    <entity name="Question" local-service="true" uuid="true">


        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="questionId" primary="true" type="long"></column>

        <!-- Group instance -->

        <column name="groupId" type="long"></column>

        <!-- Audit fields -->

        <column name="companyId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userId" type="long"></column>
        <column name="userName" type="String"></column>
        <column name="createDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date"></column>
        <column name="title" type="String"></column>
        <column name="summary" type="String"></column>
        <column name="description" type="String"></column>
        <column name="status" type="int" />
        <column name="statusByUserId" type="long" />
        <column name="statusByUserName" type="String" />
        <column name="statusDate" type="Date" />
        
        <finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="groupId"></finder-column>
        </finder>
        <reference entity="Group" package-path="com.liferay.portal"></reference>
    </entity>
    <exceptions>
        <exception>QuestionValidation</exception>
    </exceptions>
</service-builder>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I miss to add a *service* attribute to the component annotation in the **QuestionPermission** class.

```
service = QuestionPermission.class
```

After adding it, it works fine. It would look like this:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = QuestionPermission.class
)
```